# Possible to Draw a Loop With HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

We are currently using HighCharts for our typical bar, pie, line charts.  But, we have been asked to plot some medical data that would end up resembling an irregular loop.

[image: Loop]

If I have an array of x,y points, would it be possible for me to draw this sort of graph with HighCharts?  And, if so, can you point me to the right section of the documentation.  I see that drawing things like rectangles and circles is possible, but I haven't found any info on drawing lines between arbitrary points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see only three ways to achieve that, and none of them is easy, and have some limitations:

1) Use `spline` series with unsorted data - looks almost good, only tooltip doesn't work for unsorted data

2) Use `scatter` series with unsorted data - issue with tooltip is gone, but curves aren't smooth

3) Use `renderer.path` - doesn't have tooltip at all, and requires to add path manually.

And example of all three: http://jsfiddle.net/kEu3w/